# What is Man? (7)

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

What is Man? (7)

Please replace the characters in the grids with the correct characters.

[image: Puzzle]

Hint:

> Look for the entry point. No computer or special knowledge required to make some progress, until the finish line becomes obvious.

Hint 2:

> What is man?
>  (7)!

Comment: "What is a man? [flings his wine glass aside] A miserable little pile of secrets! But enough talk! Have at you!"

Comment: Are the specific colors chosen significant or are they just there to distinguish one from the other?

Comment: @Prim3numbah The latter.

Comment: @Chengarda EN GARDE! BEHOLD MY EVIL PLAN, THE MODERN ARTE!

Comment: Hmm, I've tried various programmatic approaches to decoding this, but nothing yet. I think while 1kgh11d on the left is probably a 7-letter word, 2abcdeaf and gjichjd below might be phrases/multiple words or not words at all.

Comment: If it helps anyone, I converted most of the puzzle (minus red lines) to a google spreadsheet:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iBfJRd39H7227Qq2ND9hVWbbsO3BQfYr5VO35sANxfk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What is man?

> **Curious**

The entry point:

> The second hint re-emphasizes the title: "What is man? (7)" Let's assume that each single character represents a single charcter, albeit usually not itself. In that case, the lower part of the cells at the bottom **gjichjd!** could be a seven letter word.
>
>  The line above that, **2abcdeaf?**, is a question. If **2** represents (any) two characters, that question could be "What is man?" and **a**, which occurs twice in that line, represents itself, "a". The letters "b" to "f" ar also known; thy represent **t**, **i**, **s**, **m** and **n** respectively.

The next step:

> The bottom line of the large grid in the top right, **2ehdaπ1fd** becomes **2**m**h**sa**π1**ns. Now **2** is any two characters again and the Greek letter **π** represents its name in Latin characters, "pi". We get **homo sapiens**, which is related to the question "What is man?"

Finishing the grid:

> The line above that also starts with **homo**, the previous one with **hom**. The top line, where **3** means any three letters, could be **animalia**, the kingdom of Homo sapiens.
>
>  So the seven boxes to the left are the first letters of the levels of the Linnean classification. The seven words that are underlined in red in the large grid give the classification of [Homo sapiens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human):
>
>  **K**ingdom:        **Animalia**
>  **P**hylum:         **Chordata**
>  **C**lass:          **Mammalia**
>  **O**rder:          **Primates**
>  **F**amily:         **Hominidae**
>  **G**enus:          **Homo**
>  **S**pecies:        **Homo sapiens**

So, what is man?

> With the letters that have already been identified, the bottom line is **c**j**rio**j**s**! The "j" occurs twice and represents the same letter each time. That letter is **u**.

Comment: You got it, great work!